I have a question about "AuthenticationFilter.class" in Spring Security
http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .addFilterAfter(CoustomAuthCheckFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
...

I used AuthenticationFilter.class in the addFilterAfter method and encountered an error. After changing it to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class, it worked. Why does the compiler not throw an error when using AuthenticationFilter.class even though it's not a concrete filter that is typically used directly?"
try
http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .addFilterAfter(CoustomAuthCheckFilter, AuthenticationFilter.class)

I expecting server start. but
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/wincubemkt/mediagw/global/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: The Filter class org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFilter does not have a registered order
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:971) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at com.wincubemkt.mediagw.MEDIAGWApplication.main(MEDIAGWApplication.java:11) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]

I encountered the following error when using AuthenticationFilter.class

The error on why seems pretty clear. AuthenticationFilter does not have a registered order, you can only use filters which have a specific order in the addFilterAfter/addFilterBefore as if it doesn't have an order (i.e. is part of the regular chain) how would the configuration determine where to place the filter?

Thank you for the explanation. Given that AuthenticationFilter.class does not have a registered order and cannot be used with addFilterAfter or addFilterBefore, why does Spring Security not produce a compile-time error to prevent this?

How should a method invocation lead to a compile time error? That would only work if the signature wouldn't match.

It might be an unusual thought, but what if the method:
public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> beforeFilter) were changed to: public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends FilterChain> beforeFilter) Would this modification cause any issues?

That change wouldn't make sense. You want to add a filter before/after another filter. Adding changing this to a FilterChain won't help at all (nor makes any sense).

The error message says:
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFilter does not have a registered order

which kind of tells you what the issue is. In Spring for you to use the methods:

addFilterBefore()
addFilterAfter()

the second parameter has to have an Order set by Spring inside of FilterOrderRegistration. Here is a snippet out of FilterOrderRegistration:
//...
put(X509AuthenticationFilter.class, order.next());
put(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class, order.next());
this.filterToOrder.put("org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter", order.next());
this.filterToOrder.put("org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter", order.next());
this.filterToOrder.put("org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.authentication.Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter", order.next());
put(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class, order.next());
order.next(); // gh-8105
//...

as you can see among other classes it sets an order for UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. If you look at the complete code however, it doesn't register order for AuthenticationFilter (for whatever reason).

When you call either addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter they both internally refer to the addFilterAtOffsetOf method which then throws the exception you are facing:
@Override
public HttpSecurity addFilterAfter(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> afterFilter) {
    return addFilterAtOffsetOf(filter, 1, afterFilter);
}

@Override
public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> beforeFilter) {
    return addFilterAtOffsetOf(filter, -1, beforeFilter);
}

private HttpSecurity addFilterAtOffsetOf(Filter filter, int offset, Class<? extends Filter> registeredFilter) {
    Integer registeredFilterOrder = this.filterOrders.getOrder(registeredFilter);
    if (registeredFilterOrder == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The Filter class " + registeredFilter.getName() + " does not have a registered order");
    }
    int order = registeredFilterOrder + offset;
    this.filters.add(new OrderedFilter(filter, order));
    this.filterOrders.put(filter.getClass(), order);
    return this;
}

Which is why as of this writing (Spring Security 6.3.1) you are limited to the following Filters that you can reference in addFilterAfter since these are the only ones that are registered in FilterOrderRegistration:
 - DisableEncodeUrlFilter.class
 - ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter.class
 - ChannelProcessingFilter.class
 - WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class
 - SecurityContextHolderFilter.class
 - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class
 - HeaderWriterFilter.class
 - CorsFilter.class
 - CsrfFilter.class
 - LogoutFilter.class
 - X509AuthenticationFilter.class
 - AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class
 - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
 - DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.class
 - DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.class
 - ConcurrentSessionFilter.class
 - DigestAuthenticationFilter.class
 - BasicAuthenticationFilter.class
 - RequestCacheAwareFilter.class
 - SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class
 - JaasApiIntegrationFilter.class
 - RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class
 - AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class
 - SessionManagementFilter.class
 - ExceptionTranslationFilter.class
 - FilterSecurityInterceptor.class
 - AuthorizationFilter.class
 - SwitchUserFilter.class


Thank you for the explanation. Given that AuthenticationFilter.class does not have a registered order and cannot be used with addFilterAfter or addFilterBefore, why does Spring Security not produce a compile-time error to prevent this?

Compile time errors can only be produced by Java compiler (that is why they are called compile time) when catching a Java syntax mistake.

It might be an unusual thought, but what if the method:
public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends Filter> beforeFilter)
were changed to:
public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends ChainFilter> beforeFilter)
Would this modification cause any issues?

There is no ChainFilter class so this wouldn't even compile.

sorry, no ChainFilter -> FilterChain.class
were changed to: public HttpSecurity addFilterBefore(Filter filter, Class<? extends FilterChain> beforeFilter) Would this modification cause any issues?

Becuause a Filter and a FilterChain is two different things. As the name suggests, a filter is a single filter, a FilterChain is a chain of filter, a list if you may.

but the question you should be asking yourself is, why do you even need to add a custom Filter. Its pretty clear that you are a complete beginner, so why are you not reading the docs, and using the built in filters that already come with spring security. Why dont the built in features suit your needs?

The order where the filter is placed is derived from the FilterOrderRegistration class. For the addFilterBefore and addFilterAfter it is needed to know the order for the filter so as to know where to place the filter to be added (before/after it).
The AuthenticationFilter isn't in that list of orders hence using addFilterBefore/addFilterAfter will fail as it cannot determine where to place your filter.
The addFilterBefore/addFilterAfter eventually delegate all to the private addFilterAtOffsetOf method. Which throws an exception if no order can be found.
private HttpSecurity addFilterAtOffsetOf(Filter filter, int offset, Class<? extends Filter> registeredFilter) {
    Integer registeredFilterOrder = this.filterOrders.getOrder(registeredFilter);
    if (registeredFilterOrder == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The Filter class " + registeredFilter.getName() + " does not have a registered order");
    }
    int order = registeredFilterOrder + offset;
    this.filters.add(new OrderedFilter(filter, order));
    this.filterOrders.put(filter.getClass(), order);
    return this;
}


Thank you for the explanation. Given that AuthenticationFilter.class does not have a registered order and cannot be used with addFilterAfter or addFilterBefore, why does Spring Security not produce a compile-time error to prevent this?

@minjun javac is the compiler and has no concepts about what is right or wrong about how you use Spring.  All the compiler cares about is syntax, types, scope,...

This error you are getting because you are trying to add your custom authentication filter before or after AuthenticationFilter but there is no such filter class exist in spring-security library.


and it worked after adding UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter because this filter exist in spring security library.
you can check list of all filter. Go to library org.springframework.security.web --> authentication folder.
